# (semi)-Automatic pluralization around a citation

Tags: citing, grammar

In my document, I will write something like this (using `natbib`, but that shouldn't matter too much):

```
\citet{reference} show that .....
```

which would render as

> Jones et al (1990) show that....

(`\citet` in `\natbib` creates an 'author-list (year)' reference style)

Of course if `{reference}` was a single individual, I should have written

```
\cite{reference} shows that ....
```

rendering as

> Jones (1990) shows that....

Since I'm lazy and can't take the extra 5 seconds to search the reference to see if it's a single author or not, is there conceivably an automated way to do pluralization ? Or some relatively simple macro that would look like

`\IfRefIsPlural{reference}{show}{shows}`

Comment: Are you sure your first example is grammatically correct. To me Jones and Smith (1990) seems like one thing.

Comment: I think that's right. 'Jones and Smith show...' but 'Jones and Smith (1990) shows...' because it is talking about a single article. At least, that sounds right to me. But that's presumably off-topic here. The question of whether it can be implemented is independent of whether it should be.

Comment: Maybe I should have posted on english.SE :). or at least the non-TeX part.

Answer (score 2):

With `biblatex` one could do the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

% Used in some citations
\newcounter{totalnames}
\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
    \setcounter{totalnames}{\value{author}}%
  \ifcase\value{uniquename}%
    \usebibmacro{name:family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \or
    \ifuseprefix
      {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
        {\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartgiveni}
        {\namepartprefix}
        {\namepartsuffixi}}
      {\usebibmacro{name:given-family}
        {\namepartfamily}
        {\namepartgiveni}
        {\namepartprefixi}
        {\namepartsuffixi}}%
  \or
    \usebibmacro{name:given-family}
      {\namepartfamily}
      {\namepartgiven}
      {\namepartprefix}
      {\namepartsuffix}%
  \fi
  \usebibmacro{name:andothers}}

\newcommand{\IfRefIsPlural}[2]{%
    \ifnum\thetotalnames=1
        #1%
    \else%
        #2
    \fi%
}

\begin{document}

\citet{bertram} \IfRefIsPlural{shows}{show}

\citet{angenendt} \IfRefIsPlural{shows}{show}

\printbibliography  
\end{document}
```

[image]

*(small caveat: this won't work for `\citet{bertram,angenendt}`)*